# Yii SOAP Web Service returning XML

Tags: php, xml, rest, soap, yii

I am trying to write a web service API using PHP and the Yii framework. This means that I will be using SOAP web services, since Yii does not directly support RESTful web services.

I would like to return results in XML format, as strings (this might be stupid, but I'm working with rather cumbersome data types that would make life more difficult for the web service clients trying to use them). The problem I'm facing is that the XML I'm returning contains tags, which leads to the strings not being read properly by the web service client.

For instance, I can return this string in one of my web services:

"`hello`"

But not this string:

"`<hello>`"

(An empty string is read by the client)

So, is there a way for a SOAP web service to return an XML document as a string (in general, or using Yii in particular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should really be done by the framework (don't know about Yii though), but since it doesn't seem to work automatically for you, try escaping the data first:

```
$data_to_send = htmlspecialchars($data_to_send);
```

If Yii doesn't encode the data, your client will see the correct output (the raw XML string) when fetching the data from their SOAP library. If Yii, however, does encode the data, it will get double-encoded which is probably not what you want, but if it does encode it you shouldn't have this problem in the first place...

Comment: Thanks. This does indeed seem to solve the problem. Now I just need to figure out if it's politically correct to return an XML using SOAP in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains characters that are also XML tags, you can use the CDATA option.

```
<value><![CDATA[<hello>]]></value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use soap. It is one if the worst technologies ever made (see the numerous posts on SO) . Yii does support REST now (fully as of 1.17). Just use JSON format. Do you need to delete or insert from the client?

Comment: Yii does REST eh?  Good to know.

Comment: Oh, good to know that Yii supports REST now. I will definitely look into it. However, I still have some concerns about using it, since I will need to perform insert and delete operations from the client (it is going to be a rather extensive API). Also, the security requirements are giving me some doubts about using REST. Users of the API need to be authenticated first, and sending credentials (or tokens) through the URL seems like a not-so-safe solution.

Comment: vlad.acretoaie, sending credentials through the URL is just as safe as sending them in a SOAP call (or POSTing them for that matter). In all these cases you send everything in plaintext. If you need security, use encryption (HTTPS with a certificate signed by a third party) to disarm man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: I ended up POSTing the credentials and method parameters. And yes, I will use encryption with it as well. But you're right, any form of plaintext is just plaintext in the end.